# Using ISNULL() on case expression result

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, isnull

I have a large case expression

e.g.

```
CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE
CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE '' END ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE
CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE '' END ELSE '' END as [Test]
```

Now the [Test] column returns some NULLS. How can i wrap this CASE expression with (ISNULL, '') so that if it is NULL it is just blank?

What is the cleanest way to accomplish this with a very large case statement?

Answer (score 3):

I may be missing the point but is there something you don't like about

```
ISNULL(
    CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE
    CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE '' END ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE
    CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE '' END ELSE '' END 
    , '')
AS [Test]
```

?

Comment: I originally wanted to do this but i couldn't get it to work. Looks like i got the placement wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the entire expression with an `ISNULL`:

```
ISNULL(
CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE
CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE '' END ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE
CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE '' END ELSE '' END,'') as [Test]
```

Alternatively, you could use `CONCAT`, however, this would change the logic of your query slightly. If one expression didn't return a `NULL` and the other did, you would now get a value. `NULL + {Non NULL Expression}` = `NULL` however, `CONCAT(NULL,{Non NULL Expression})` = `{Non NULL Expression}`.:

```
CONCAT(
CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE
CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE '' END ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE
CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE '' END ELSE '' END) as [Test]
```

`CONCAT` will never return `NULL`. If every expression has the value `NULL`, an empty string (`(n)varchar`) is returned.

Answer (score 1):

I would do :

```
SELECT ISNULL([Test], '')
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE
               CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE '' END ELSE '' END +
               CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE
               CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE '' END ELSE '' END)
     ) tt ([Test]);
```

However, you can also apply `ISNULL()` to entire huge case expression :

```
SELECT ISNULL((CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE
               CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE '' END ELSE '' END +
               CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE
               CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE '' END ELSE '' END), ''
              )
. . .
```

The only advantage of `APPLY` is that you can use `[Test]` column anywhere or more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use a function for large case statement, this will be more readable for you. And easier to implement your solutions.